# strip space between one letter words

Tags: php, preg-replace, strip

How would you strip spaces between one letter words. Example:

- string: **"T I G R U S FOO and Drezga d . o . o .  New York"**
- we want: **"TIGRUS FOO and Drezga d.o.o. New York"**

If possible preg_replace solution, sorry for not telling before.

Comment: i tried some preg_replace codes, but i haven`t got far, thus not writing it in question. best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this php code:

```
<?php
   $str = "T I G R U S FOO and Drezga d . o . o . New York";
   $out = preg_replace('~(\b.)\s~', "\\1", $str);
   var_dump($out);
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
string(38) "TIGRUSFOO and Drezga d. o. o. New York
```

### UPDATE

```
<?php
   $str = "T I G R U S FOO and Drezga d . o . o . New York N Y";
   $s = preg_replace('~((?<=^[^\s])|(?<=\s[^\s]))\s(?=[^\s](\s|$))~', "", $str);
   var_dump($s);
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
string(40) "TIGRUS FOO and Drezga d.o.o. New York NY"
```

?>

Comment: -1 The output doesn't match what was asked.  The expected output is: "TIGRUS FOO and Drezga d.o.o. New York"  You have additional spaced between d.o.o. and are missing a space between "TIGRUS" and "FOO."

Comment: this is the closest solution. if we could only resolve space between TIGRUS and FOO. I guess it should check if next letter has space as next caracter. And much nicer than first one, i would like to handle this with preg_replace if it is possible.

Comment: @Luka & @Gazler: Had to step out after posting my answer today. Read your comments and reworked my answer to generate expected output behavior using pure regex solution. However IMO this regex is little bit complicated since it require putting some logic in it as per OP's question.

Comment: @anubhava, downvote removed as the solution now matches what was asked.

Comment: @Luka & @Gazler: Thanks a lot, glad that you both liked the solution. Ended up spending couple of hours to figure it out using 100% regex based solution :)

Answer (score 3):

The following works.

```
$string = "T I G R U S FOO and Drezga d . o . o . New York";

$words = explode(" ", $string);

$output = array();
$temp_word = "";
foreach($words as $word)
{
    if (strlen($word) == 1)
    {
        $temp_word .= $word;
    }
    else
    {
        if ($temp_word != "")
        {
            $output[] = $temp_word;
            $temp_word = "";
        }
        $output[] = $word;
    }
}

$output = implode(" ", $output);
echo $output;
```

Outputs: "TIGRUS FOO and Drezga d.o.o. New York"

Comment: Strictly speaking, this will incorrectly handle cases where you'll want a single character on its own (there are several common words like that, and not just in English).  But it might be good enough for your purposes.

Comment: @Austin, good point, something to be aware of if the asker uses this solution.

Comment: Galzer thanks, but i wanted preg_replace solution if possible, this is little nasty one, but thanks for your effort. best, luka

Answer (score 0):

<strike>That's not possible, unfortunately.  There is no easy way to distinguish single-space word boundaries from extraneous single-spaces between a word's characters.</strike>

EDIT: Retracted -- I made the assumption that the replacement would need to properly handle (i.e. keep separate) words that are actually one character long.

Comment: It is possible. Read the question again, it says "spaces between one letter words"